# filesize has to be greater than 0 php write files aldough the code is prepared to prevent the error

Tags: php, file, filesize

I'm trying to write in a file and I get this error aldough the code is prepared to prevent that error.

```
$filename = "uploads/stories/".$row['s_source'];
    echo $filename;
    echo "<br>";
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r+");
    echo filesize($filename);
    if (filesize($filename) == 0) {
        $txt = "{====views====}{====likes====}{====chapters====}{====comments====}";
        fwrite($handle, $txt);
    }
    $content = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);

    echo $scontent;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $content;

    $txt = "|||title:".$schaptername."|||".$scontent."|||";

    $handle = fopen($filename, "w");
```

And this returns:

> uploads/stories/story1.30.txt
>
> 0
>
> Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0 in E:\xampp\htdocs\host\host\submitchapter.php on line 29
>
> ...............

This means that the

```
    if (filesize($filename) == 0) {
        $txt = "{====views====}{====likes====}{====chapters====}{====comments====}";
        fwrite($handle, $txt);
    }
```

is not working, aldough the `filesize($filename)` is 0

Could someone make this work?

Comment: Try seeing what the `filesize` is after you write to the file.

Comment: Calling fwrite() doesn't guarantee to have immediate effect, until you close the handle. And filesize() counts the _actual_ file size. Also, typo in `$scontent` - one `s` more. Generally, it is not a good practice to "sneak in" some content that you read afterwards. Not needed either.